# Convert RGBA PNG to RGB with TensorFlow

Tags: python-3.x, rgb, tensorflow2.0, rgba, image-conversion

I used the module  `tensorflow.image` with `TensorFlow v2.0.0` for open an image, using the code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
img = tf.image.decode_png(tf.io.read_file("image.png"))
```

But this image is **RGB-A**. How could I convert it to **RGB**?

(Preferably, only using `TensorFlow`)

Answer (score 2):

The function

```
tf.io.decode_png(
contents, channels=0, dtype=tf.dtypes.uint8, name=None
)
```

allows you to choose the type of color model you want to use for the image you are importing.

The attr `channels` indicates the desired number of color channels for the decoded image.

Accepted values are:

0: Use the number of channels in the PNG-encoded image.

1: output a grayscale image.

3: output an RGB image.

4: output an RGBA image.

If you want to import an **RGB-A** image as an **RGB** image, just use the code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
img = tf.image.decode_png(tf.io.read_file("image.png"), channels=3)
```

Comment: Great answer! Save me so much time